# How to remove textbox autofill on email and password in adb2c custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is there a way to remove autofill from email and password field in adb2c with custom policies?

Comment: Where are you seeing the autofill? What flow? Is this on mobile? Are you using the Authenticator app?

Comment: on the login screen , we have implemented a basic sigin flow. when the user is redirected to sign in flow - email and password are autofill from the browser which we want to restrict from happening

Comment: So this is browser functionality? If so, no, there is no way to restrict this from the custom policy.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you rbrayb for the comment.

It seems to be browser functionality. No way to restrict this from the AAD B2C custom policy.

Clear cache and history and Clear saved password and email ID's on browser.

Also change instead of autocomplete="off" use autocomplete="false" on Chrome

[image]